# Appending data to another workbook/file

Tags: excel, vba, append, transfer

I have this code:

```
    Private Sub TransfertoWrkBtn_Click()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim fSource As Worksheet
    Dim TargetBook As Workbook
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim fTarget As Worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer")
    Set fSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Family")

flname = InputBox("Enter File Name :", "Creating New File...")

If flname <> "" Then
     Set TargetBook = Workbooks.Add

  TargetBook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\MSN\" & flname
  TargetBook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Family"
  TargetBook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Customer"

End If


Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer")

   j = 2     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
   For Each c In Source.Range("v1:v10000")   ' Do 1000 rows
       If c = flname Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
          End If
    Next c


Set fTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Family")

j = 2     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
   For Each i In fSource.Range("n1:n10000")
       If i = flname Then
           fSource.Rows(i.Row).Copy fTarget.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
          End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

This code only creating a new file copy the data and deleting the existing file.
I need a way to check if the file exists and if so to check if current row needs to be updated or/and added.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the filename in the variable `flname` exists, use the `Dir()` function.

```
If Dir(flname) = "" Then
  Msgbox("File does not exist.")
  Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: And check if the current row needs updating  or adding?